# What's the correct approach to solve SPOJ www.spoj.com/problems/PRHYME/?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, trie

I have been trying to solve this problem SPOJ www.spoj.com/problems/PRHYME/? for several days, but have had no success.
Here is the problem in brief:

> Given is a wordlist L, and a word w. Your task is to find a word in L that forms a perfect rhyme with w. This word u is uniquely determined by these properties:
>
> - It is in L.
> - It is different from w.
> - Their common suffix is as long as possible.
> - Out of all words that satisfy the previous points, u is the lexicographically smallest one.
>
> Length of a word will be<=30.
>   And number of words both in the dictionary and the queries can be 2,50,000.

I am using a trie to store all the words in the dictionary reversed.
Then to solve the queries I proceed in the following fashion:-

1. If word is present in the trie,delete it from trie.
2. Now traverse the trie from the root till the point the character from the query string match the trie values.Let this point where last character match was found be P.
3. Now from this point P onward ,I traverse the trie using DFS,and on encountering a leaf node,push the string formed to the possible results list.
4. Now I return the lexicographic ally smallest result from this list.

When I submit my  solution on SPOJ,my solution gets a Time Limit Exceeded Error.

Can someone please suggest a detailed algorithm or hint to solve this problem ?
I can post my code if required.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<climits>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cctype>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<utility>
#include<map>
#include<queue>
#include<set>
#define  ll long long signed int
#define ull unsigned long long int 


const int alpha=26;


using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int value;
    node * child[alpha]; 
};
node * newnode()
{
    node * newt=new node;
    newt->value=0;
    for(int i=0;i<alpha;i++)
    {
        newt->child[i]=NULL;
    }
    return newt;
}

struct trie
{
   node * root;
   int count;
   trie()
   {
      count=0;
      root=newnode();
   }
};
trie * dict=new trie;


string reverse(string s)
{
   int l=s.length();
   string rev=s;
   for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
   {
       int j=l-1-i;
       rev[j]=s[i];

   }

   return rev;  
}
void insert(string s)
{
    int l=s.length();
    node * ptr=dict->root;
    dict->count++;
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
       int index=s[i]-'a';
       if(ptr->child[index]==NULL)
       {
         ptr->child[index]=newnode();
       }
       ptr=ptr->child[index];
    }
    ptr->value=dict->count;

}
void dfs1(node *ptr,string p)
{
   if(ptr==NULL) return;
   if(ptr->value)  cout<<"word" <<p<<endl;
   for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
   {    
         if(ptr->child[i]!=NULL)
         dfs1(ptr->child[i],p+char('a'+i));
   }

}

vector<string> results;
pair<node *,string> search(string s)
{
    int l=s.length();
    node * ptr=dict->root;
    node *save=ptr;
    string match="";
    int i=0;
    bool no_match=false;
    while(i<l and !no_match)
    {
        int in=s[i]-'a';
        if(ptr->child[in]==NULL)
        {

          save=ptr;
          no_match=true;
        }
        else
        {

           ptr=ptr->child[in];
           save=ptr;
           match+=in+'a';
        }
        i++;

    }
    //cout<<s<<" matched till here"<<match <<" "<<endl;
    return make_pair(save,match);


}
bool  find(string s)
{
    int l=s.length();
    node * ptr=dict->root;
    string match="";
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
          int in=s[i]-'a';
          //cout<<match<<"match"<<endl;
         if(ptr->child[in]==NULL)
         {
           return false;
         }
         ptr=ptr->child[in];
        match+=char(in+'a');
    }
    //cout<<match<<"match"<<endl;

    return true;



}
bool leafNode(node *pNode)
{
    return (pNode->value != 0);
}

bool isItFreeNode(node *pNode)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < alpha; i++)
    {
        if( pNode->child[i] )
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
bool deleteHelper(node *pNode, string key, int level, int len)
{
    if( pNode )
    {
        // Base case
        if( level == len )
        {
            if( pNode->value )
            {
                // Unmark leaf node
                pNode->value = 0;

                // If empty, node to be deleted
                if( isItFreeNode(pNode) )
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
        else // Recursive case
        {
            int index = (key[level])-'a';

            if( deleteHelper(pNode->child[index], key, level+1, len) )
            {
                // last node marked, delete it
                free(pNode->child[index]);
                pNode->child[index]=NULL;

                // recursively climb up, and delete eligible nodes
                return ( !leafNode(pNode) && isItFreeNode(pNode) );
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
void deleteKey(string key)
{
    int len = key.length();

    if( len > 0 )
    {
        deleteHelper(dict->root, key, 0, len);
    }
}
string result="***";
void dfs(node *ptr,string p)
{
   if(ptr==NULL) return;
   if(ptr->value )  
   {
       if((result)=="***")
       {
          result=reverse(p);
       }
       else
       {
          result=min(result,reverse(p));
       }

   }
   for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
   {    
         if(ptr->child[i]!=NULL)
         dfs(ptr->child[i],p+char('a'+i));
   }

}
int main(int argc ,char ** argv)
{
         #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
         freopen("prhyme.in","r",stdin);
         #endif
        string s;
         while(getline(cin,s,'\n'))
         {


            if(s[0]<'a' and s[0]>'z')
            break;
           int l=s.length();
           if(l==0) break;
           string  rev;//=new char[l+1];
           rev=reverse(s);

        insert(rev);
        //cout<<"...........traverse..........."<<endl;
        //dfs(dict->root);       
        //cout<<"..............traverse end.............."<<endl;         

         }      
          while(getline(cin,s))
         {



            results.clear();
            //cout<<s<<endl;
            int l=s.length();
            if(!l) break;
            string rev;//=new char[l+1];
            rev=reverse(s);
            //cout<<rev<<endl;
            bool del=false;
            if(find(rev))
            {
              del=true;
              //cout<<"here found"<<endl;
              deleteKey(rev);
            }
             if(find(rev))
            {
              del=true;
              //cout<<"here found"<<endl;
              deleteKey(rev);
            }
            else
            {
              //cout<<"not here found"<<endl;
            }
          // cout<<"...........traverse..........."<<endl;
        //dfs1(dict->root,"");       
     // cout<<"..............traverse end.............."<<endl;         
            pair<node *,string> pp=search(rev);

            result="***";   
            dfs(pp.first,pp.second);
            //cout<<"search results"<<endl;
            //dfs1(pp.first,pp.second);
            //cout<<"end of search results"<<
            for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++)
            {
               results[i]=reverse(results[i]);
              // cout<<s<<" "<<results[i]<<endl;
            }
            string smin=result;

            if(del)
            {
               insert(rev);
            }
            cout<<smin<<endl;
         }  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code usually helps. Also, is number of words in the dictionary supposed to be 2,500,000 or 250,000? Also, do you know what the maximum amount of time is you are allowed?

Comment: 2,50,000  strings max

Comment: 2,50,000 strings is not a valid number. Which is it: 2,500,000 or 250,000?

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm (using a trie that stores all reversed words) is a good start. But one issue with it is that for each lookup, you have to enumerate all words with a certain suffix in order to find the lexicographically smallest one. For some cases, this can be a lot of work.

One way to fix this: In each node (corresponding to each suffix), store the two lexicographically smallest words that have that suffix. This is easy to maintain while building the trie by updating all ancestor nodes of each newly added leaf (see pseudo-code below).

Then to perform a lookup of a word `w`, start at the node corresponding to the word, and go up in the tree until you reach a node which contains a descendant word other than `w`. Then return the lexicographically smallest word stored in that node, or the second smallest in case the smallest is equal to `w`.

To create the trie, the following pseudo-code can be used:

```
for each word:
    add word to trie
    let n be the node corresponding to the new word.
    for each ancestor a of n (including n):
        if a.smallest==null or word < a.smallest:
            a.second_smallest = a.smallest
            a.smallest = word
        else if a.second_smallest==null or word < a.second_smallest:
            a.second_smallest = word
```

To lookup a word `w`:

```
let n be the node corresponding to longest possible suffix of w.
while ((n.smallest==w || n.smallest==null) && 
       (n.second_smallest==w || n.second_smallest==null)):
    n = n.parent
if n.smallest==w:
    return n.second_smallest
else:
    return n.smallest
```

Another similar possibility is to use a hash table mapping all suffixes to the two lexicographically smallest words instead of using a trie. This is probably easier to implement if you can use `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Can you  state your suggested algorithms in terms of steps.

Comment: @user1907531 I thought I did. I'll try to clarify when I have time, but it will help if you say which part wasn't clear.

Comment: This is easy to maintain while building the trie by updating all ancestor nodes of each newly added leaf.
 This part is not clear.can you write pseudo code for it or explain this in more detail

Comment: Also,are you storing words reversed or not

Comment: And  n in your pseudocode,does it represent the leaf node where the word ends

Comment: Also,it seems the above pseudo code won't work for all cases .Can you explain how it would work for 2 words crime and time  and if the query words are time,crime and ime

Comment: @user1907531: The words are stored reversed. `n` is the node where the word ends. For your example, the node `ime` would have `smallest==crime` and `second_smallest==time`. All three queries would reach this node and select `crime` if possible, otherwise `time`.